# How to get a reference to the module something is implemented in from within that implementation?

Tags: python, module

Say I have the following code:

```
 from foo.bar import Foo
 from foo.foo import Bar

 __all__ = ["Foo", "Bar"]

 def iterate_over_all():
     ...
```

How can I implement code in the function `iterate_over_all()` that can dynamically obtain references to whatever is referenced in `__all__` the module where the function is implemented?  IE: in `iterate_over_all()` I want to work with `foo.bar.Foo` and `foo.foo.Bar`.

Comment: Can you clarify the question a bit? Are you saying you want to be able to go from the string "Foo" to the object Foo and then to the module which contains Foo?

Comment: I'm not getting it: You want a reference to something that is in __all__, e.g. "Foo", so you want to get from "Foo" to Foo, is that right?! Or you want to get from "Foo" to foo.bar?! The part *"...referenced in __all__ the module where..."* is kind of difficult.

Comment: Sorry guys, clarification added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this do?

```
def iterate_over_all():
    for name in __all__:
        value = globals()[name]
        yield value # or do whatever with it
```

Comment: You're right, *globals()* is actually nicer than trying to get to *\_\_dict\_\_*, and for the purpose of this question it seems to have the same keys with the right references.

Answer (score 0):

`eval` is one way. e.g. `eval("Foo")` would give you `Foo`. However you can also just put Foo and Bar directly in your list e.g. `__all__ = [Foo, Bar]`

It would depend on where the contents of `__all__` is coming from in your actual program.

Comment: Hi Mike, yes this would work but according to the docs these should be strings: "he import statement uses the following convention: if a package’s __init__.py code defines a list named __all__, it is taken to be the list of module names that should be imported when from package import * is encountered." (http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html?highlight=__all__)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Would looking the items up in globals() work? e.g. globals()["Foo"]

Comment: @mikej Yes, I would say so, see Martin's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily index with the strings from *__all__* into the module's *__dict__*:

```
__dict__["Foo"] == foo.bar.Foo  # -> True
```

Comment: Thomas: great answer, but how to get a reference to that module's dict?

Comment: Ah, I thought *\_\_dict\_\_* would be available right away... Here is a way to get it: *sys.modules[globals()[\_\_name\_\_]].\_\_dict\_\_*. (Gee, I wished there was a *self* on the module level ...).

Comment: It's actually funny that other module attributes are freely available, like *\_\_name\_\_* and *\_\_file\_\_*, while *\_\_dict\_\_* is not...

Comment: Indeed it is!  I was puzzled by that.